# How to get a count of records by minute using a datetime column

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table with columns below:

| Customer | Time_Start |
| --- | --- |
| A | 01/20/2020 01:25:00 |
| A | 01/22/2020 14:15:00 |
| A | 01/20/2020 03:23:00 |
| A | 01/21/2020 20:37:00 |

I am trying to get a table that outputs a table by minute (including zeros) for a given day.

i.e.

| Customer | Time_Start | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01/20/2020 00:01:00 | 5 |
| A | 01/20/2020 00:02:00 | 2 |
| A | 01/20/2020 00:03:00 | 0 |
| A | 01/20/2020 00:04:00 | 12 |

I would like to have it show only 1 day for 1 customer at a time.

Here is what I have so far:

```
select 
customer,
cast(time_start as time) + ((cast(time_start as time) - cast('00:00:00' as time)) hour(2)) as TimeStampHour,
count(*) as count
from    Table_1
where   customer in ('A')
group by    customer, TimeStampHour
order by    TimeStampHour
```

Comment: What's your Teradata release? This is an easy task for *time series aggregation*

Comment: I am on 16.10.0.2

Comment: For @dnoeth to know that you replied, you have to tag him, like I just did for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Teradata 16.20 this would be a simple task using the new *time series aggregation*

```
SELECT 
   customer
  ,Cast(Begin($Td_TimeCode_Range) AS VARCHAR(16))
  ,Count(*)
FROM table_1
WHERE customer = 'A'
  AND time_start BETWEEN TIMESTAMP'2020-01-20 00:00:00' 
                     AND Prior(TIMESTAMP'2020-01-20 00:00:00' + INTERVAL '1' DAY)
GROUP BY TIME(Minutes(1) AND customer) 
         USING timecode(time_start)
         FILL (0)
;
```

Before you must implement it similar to Ramin Faracov [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70027810/2527905), create a list of all minutes first and then left join to it. But I prefer doing the count *before* joining:

```
WITH all_minutes AS
 ( -- create a list of all minutes
   SELECT 
      Begin(pd) AS bucket
   FROM 
    ( -- EXPAND ON requires FROM and TRUNC materializes the FROM avoiding error
      -- "9303. EXPAND ON clause must not be specified in a query expression with no table references."
      SELECT Cast(Trunc(DATE '2020-01-20') AS TIMESTAMP(0)) AS start_date
    ) AS dt
   EXPAND ON PERIOD(start_date, start_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY) AS pd
          BY INTERVAL '1' MINUTE  
 )
SELECT customer
  ,bucket
  ,Coalesce(Cnt, 0)
FROM all_minutes
LEFT JOIN
 (
   SELECT customer
     ,time_start
      - (Extract (SECOND From time_start) * INTERVAL '1' SECOND) AS time_minute
      ,Count(*) AS Cnt
   FROM table_1
   WHERE customer = 'A'
     AND time_start BETWEEN TIMESTAMP'2020-01-20 00:00:00' 
                        AND Prior(TIMESTAMP'2020-01-20 00:00:00' + INTERVAL '1' DAY)
   GROUP BY customer, time_minute
 ) AS counts
ON counts.time_minute = bucket 
ORDER BY bucket
;
```

Comment: This is super helpful.  The only issue I see is this only would show 1 customer.  What if there is customer A on 1/20/2020 and customer B on 7/15/2021?  How would I show all 2880 lines?

Comment: You wrote *only 1 day for 1 customer at a time* :-) Different customers at different dates in the same result? You need to elaborate on the rules which customer(s)/day(s) should be included and why...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we create a function that returns a table that has one field and records starting from the `time_start` value and increasing one minute period.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_dates(time_start timestamp without time zone)
 RETURNS TABLE(list_dates timestamp without time zone)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
    time_end timestamp;
begin
    time_end = time_start + interval '1 day';
    
    return query 
    SELECT t1.dates
    FROM   generate_series(time_start, time_end, interval '1 min') t1(dates);
        
END;
$function$
;
```

Consider that, this function return's list of timestamp which has an hour and minute, but seconds and milliseconds are always equal to zero. We must join this result of function with our `customer` table, using the `timestamp` fields. But our `customer` table's timestamp field has a full DateTime format, second and millisecond are not empty. Hence it is, understood that our join conditions will not be correct. We need that, in `customer` table all data of the timestamp field always have an empty second and empty millisecond for correct joining. And for this, I created an immutable function, when you send to this function fully formatted DateTime `2021-02-03 18:24:51.203` then the function will be return timestamps that are empty second and empty millisecond, on this format: `2021-02-03 18:24:00.000`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clear_seconds_from_datetime(dt timestamp without time zone)
 RETURNS timestamp without time zone
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 IMMUTABLE
AS $function$
DECLARE
    str_date text;
    str_hour text; 
    str_min text;
    v_ret timestamp; 
begin

    str_date = (dt::date)::text; 
    str_hour = (extract(hour from dt))::text;
    str_min = (extract(min from dt))::text;

    str_date = str_date || ' ' || str_hour || ':' || str_min || ':' || '00';
    v_ret = str_date::timestamp; 
    return v_ret; 

END;
$function$
;
```

Why our function is immutable? For high performance, I want to use the function-based index on PostgreSQL. But, PostgreSQL is required to use only immutable functions on indexes. We use this function in the condition of the joining process. Now let's view the process of creating a function-based index:

```
CREATE INDEX customer_date_function_idx ON customer USING btree ((clear_seconds_from_datetime(datestamp)));
```

Let's go write the main query that's we need:

```
select 
    t1.list_dates, 
    cc.userid, 
    count(cc.id) as count_as
from 
    get_dates('2021-02-03 00:01:00'::timestamp) t1 (list_dates)
left join 
    customer cc on clear_seconds_from_datetime(cc.datestamp) = t1.list_dates
group by t1.list_dates, cc.userid
```

I inserted 30 million sample data into a `customer` table for testing. But, this query run's for 33 milliseconds. View the query plan for the resulting `explain analyze` command:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=309264.30..309432.30 rows=16800 width=20) (actual time=26.076..26.958 rows=2022 loops=1)
  Group Key: t1.list_dates, lg.userid
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.68..253482.75 rows=7437540 width=16) (actual time=18.870..24.882 rows=2023 loops=1)
        ->  Function Scan on get_dates t1  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=18.699..18.906 rows=1441 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using log_date_cast_idx on log lg  (cost=0.43..179.09 rows=7438 width=16) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=1441)
              Index Cond: (clear_seconds_from_datetime(datestamp) = t1.list_dates)
Planning Time: 0.398 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 12
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 3.544 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.816 ms, Emission 16.709 ms, Total 21.069 ms
Execution Time: 31.429 ms
```

Result:

| list_dates | group_count |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-03 09:41:00.000 | 1 |
| 2021-02-03 09:42:00.000 | 3 |
| 2021-02-03 09:43:00.000 | 1 |
| 2021-02-03 09:44:00.000 | 3 |
| 2021-02-03 09:45:00.000 | 1 |
| 2021-02-03 09:46:00.000 | 5 |
| 2021-02-03 09:47:00.000 | 2 |
| 2021-02-03 09:48:00.000 | 1 |
| 2021-02-03 09:49:00.000 | 1 |
| 2021-02-03 09:50:00.000 | 1 |
| 2021-02-03 09:51:00.000 | 4 |
| 2021-02-03 09:52:00.000 | 0 |
| 2021-02-03 09:53:00.000 | 0 |
| 2021-02-03 09:54:00.000 | 2 |
| 2021-02-03 09:55:00.000 | 1 |

Comment: The question states Teradata? Not PostgreSQL?

Comment: @MatBailie it is Teradata.  Thanks for this